Style Individual font that match input value
I am working on a predictive text project. There is a search bar, and a ul with a filtered list of items will appear based on users' input value.
How do I style the fonts to bold in the li that match the input value? And it does not affect the order of each character in the li?
Let's say a user enter "ap", "Apple" and "Grape" show up with the "ap" bolded in the suggestions.


const fruit = ["Apple", "Banana", "Grape", ]
let results = [];

function search(str) {
  results = [
    ...fruit.filter((el) => el.toLowerCase().includes(str.toLowerCase())),
  ];

  return results;
}

function searchHandler(e) {
  results = [];
  suggestions.textContent = "";

  showSuggestions(search(input.value), input.value);
}

function showSuggestions(results, inputVal) {
  for (let el of results) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    const span = document.createElement("span");

    span.className = "has-suggestions";

    // for each character that matches, style it bold
    li.textContent = el;

    li.append(span);
    suggestions.append(li);
    console.log(li.innerHTML);
  }
}
ul .has-suggestions {
  font-weight: bold;
}
<div class="search-container">
  <input type="text" name="fruit" id="fruit" placeholder="Search fruit " />
  <div class="suggestions">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
</div>




Your code doesn't have an event-handler to handle any text entered into the <input> element, and you're assigning properties to the suggestions object without declaring it anywhere. I think I can understand what you're asking, but for us to answer the question you need to share enough of your code that we can just edit the code to solve the problem, rather than potentially rewriting it. It's possible that I'm just tired, and not reading the code properly though.

I assumed that you want your search suggestion to be case insensitive, you can do it like this:


const fruit = ["Apple", "Banana", "Grape",]
let results = [];

function search(str) {
  results = [
    ...fruit.filter((el) => el.toLowerCase().includes(str.toLowerCase())),
  ];

  return results;
}

function searchHandler(e) {
  results = [];
  let ul = document.querySelector('.suggestions > ul');
  ul.textContent = "";
  let input = document.getElementById('fruit');
  showSuggestions(search(input.value), input.value);
}

function showSuggestions(results, inputVal) {
  let ul = document.querySelector('.suggestions > ul');
  let regex = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
  for (let el of results) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = el.replace(regex,`<span class="has-suggestions">$&</span>`);
    // $& is the matched substring to the regex
    ul.append(li);
    //console.log(li.innerHTML);
  }
}
ul .has-suggestions {
  font-weight: bold;
}
<div class="search-container">
    <input
      type="text"
      name="fruit"
      id="fruit"
      placeholder="Search fruit "
      oninput="searchHandler(event)"
    />
    <div class="suggestions">
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
</div>




What if it needs to be case sensitive? How can I achieve that? Now, when I start typing in the search bar, all matches show up in the ul become lowercase. How can I find the match, style the match fonts, and keep the uppercase in the list item?

@Kwok you can remove 'i' in regex to make it case sensive and add .toLowerCase() after el.replace() (so it becomes el.replace().toLowerCase()) to make the matches lowercase. I'll edit the answer if you need explaination.
